# How to implement target-action-mechanism for custom control?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm going to write my own custom control that is very different from UIButton. It's so much different that I decided to write it from scratch. So all I subclass is UIControl.

When my control is touched up inside, then I want to fire a message in means of target-action. The user of that class may instantiate it and then add some targets and actions for this event.

i.e. imagine I would call internally a method -fireTargetsForTouchUpEvent. How could I maintain this target-action-mechanism in my class? Do I have to add all targets and actions to my own array and then just call selectors (the actions) on the target objects in a for-loop? Or is there a more intelligent way to do it?

I imagine to provide some methods for adding targets and actions for some events like that touch up event (I raise that manually by calling a internal method when that happens). Any idea?

Comment: Usually controls have one target, one selector per event. Do you want more?

Comment: Could I have more, if I wanted? I think yes... but not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're planning to subclass UIControl, you can just use

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

Using this, any class can register itself as a target for any events it wants to on your custom controller.

Answer (score 39):

I just want to clarify what @Felixyz said because it wasn't clear to me at first.

If you are subclassing `UIControl`, even if you are going to have a custom event, you don't have to keep track of your own targets/actions. The functionality is already there, all you have to do is call the code below in your subclass to trigger the event:

`[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Then in the view or view controller that instantiates your custom `UIControl`, just do

`[customControl addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

For custom event, just define your own enum (for example, `UIControlEventValueChanged` is equal to `1 << 12`). Just make sure it is within the permitted range defined by [UIControlEventApplicationReserved](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/sendAction:to:forEvent:)

Answer (score 15):

You have the right idea. Here is how I would do it:

```
@interface TargetActionPair : NSObject
{
    id target;
    SEL action;
}
@property (assign) id target;
@property (assign) SEL action;
+ (TargetActionPair *)pairWithTarget:(id)aTarget andAction:(SEL)selector;
- (void)fire;
@end

@implementation TargetActionPair
@synthesize target;
@synthesize action;

+ (TargetActionPair *)pairWithTarget:(id)aTarget andAction:(SEL)anAction
{
    TargetActionPair * newSelf = [[self alloc] init];
    [newSelf setTarget:aTarget];
    [newSelf setAction:anAction];
    return [newSelf autorelease];
}

- (void)fire
{
    [target performSelector:action];
}

@end
```

With that class in place, storing your target/action pairs is pretty straightforward:

**MyCustomControl.h:**

```
#import "TargetActionPair.h"

@interface MyCustomControl : UIControl
{
    NSMutableArray * touchUpEventHandlers;
}

- (id)init;
- (void)dealloc;

- (void)addHandlerForTouchUp:(TargetActionPair *)handler;

@end
```

**MyCustomControl.m:**

```
#import "TargetActionPair.h"

@implementation MyCustomControl

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) { return nil; }
    touchUpEventHandlers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [touchUpEventHandlers release];
}

- (void)addHandlerForTouchUp:(TargetActionPair *)handler
{
    [touchUpEventHandlers addObject:handler];
}

- (void) fireTargetsForTouchUpEvent
{
    [touchUpEventHandlers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(fire)];
}

@end
```

After that, setting up the control would be done as follows:

```
[instanceOfMyControl addHandlerForTouchUp:
         [TargetActionPair pairWithTarget:someController
                                andAction:@selector(touchUpEvent)];
```

Comment: wow, the biggest answer I've ever got here ;) thanks! For my case, I figured out UIControl seems to offer me already what I need. But when there are special custom events that need to be processed, your technique is excellent!

Comment: Actually, for custom events you might want to use the UIControlEventApplicationReserved bits (16 available) and call -(void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;

Comment: What's missing here is a way to remove a target/action and maybe a duplicate check.