# How to observe the touchInside properties of UIControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, uicontrol

I needs to observe the touchInside properties of UIControl, But since It can't work by using KVO. Who can tell me, how to solve this problem?

```
#define SB_NORMAL_BORDER_COLOR [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.751 alpha:1.000].CGColor
#define SB_TOUCH_BORDER_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:0.077 green:0.627 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000].CGColor
#define SB_OBSERVER_KEYPATH @"touchInside"

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
        self.layer.borderColor=SB_NORMAL_BORDER_COLOR;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.881 green:0.901 blue:0.810 alpha:1.000];
        self.layer.cornerRadius=self.bounds.size.width/2;

        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:SB_OBSERVER_KEYPATH options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    }
    return self;
}
```

This Class is the UIControl subClass.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    NSLog(@"Observer");
    if(![keyPath isEqualToString:SB_OBSERVER_KEYPATH]) return;

    BOOL isTouch=[change[@"new"] boolValue];

    if(isTouch){
        self.layer.borderColor=SB_TOUCH_BORDER_COLOR;
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }else{
        self.layer.borderColor=SB_NORMAL_BORDER_COLOR;
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288978/how-to-implement-target-action-mechanism-for-custom-control) will probably help you

Comment: I want to know why can't observe the touchInside properties ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a target action

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

And handle your code in there.

Then send the action further in that method:

```
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```